# Loop over first 10 of 100 subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have 100 subdirectories and I wanted to loop through the first ten of them in a bash for loop such like that:

```
for d in ./output/*[0..9];
do 
    echo $d
done
```

But the output seems not what I expected:

```
./output/405050
./output/405140
./output/405309
./output/405310
./output/405319
./output/500550
./output/500589
./output/500610
```

Why only 8 were printed and my question is how to select a fix number elements from this type of for loop.

Comment: Don't fix the number in the loop conditional;  use a counter and break out of the loop when you get to 10.  Or generate the list prior to the loop.

Comment: Thanks, may you offer an example?

Comment: an example for you: echo ./output/* | head -10 | while read d; do ... ; done

Comment: `for d in *; do ...; test $((++i)) -ge 10 && break; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*[0..9]` loops over ones that end in a `0`, `9`, or `.`. If you had written `*{0..9}` that would loop over ones ending in a digit `0` through `9`--closer, but still not right.

Try this loop, which reads the first 10 directory names in a loop. It's kinda obtuse. The primary idea is using `while read ... < <(cmd)` to read a command's output one line at a time. `IFS=` and `-r` are pedantic bits to handle directory names with whitespace and backslashes correctly.

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    echo "$dir"
done < <(ls output/*/ | head -10)
```

Or use this more straightforward version with a counter:

```
i=0
for dir in output/*/; do
    echo "$dir"
    ((++i < 10)) || break
done
```

Or this one storing the directories in an array:

```
dirs=(output/*/)
for dir in "${dirs[@]::10}"; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @John Kugelman! For the last option how to choose 11-20 elements?

Comment: `"${dirs[@]:10:10}"` -- 0-based start index, count

Answer (score 0):

You can make a counter:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0;
for d in ./output/*/;
do
    echo $d
    echo ""

    if [[ i == 10 ]]; then
      break
    fi
    i+=1
done
```

With this you asure to get 10 folders.

I very important to do the last backslash to match only directories.